# What's about $e\zeta(3)-\zeta(6)=2e^2\int_1^2\frac{(3\zeta'(3x)-\zeta(3x))\sinh (x)}{e^{2x}-1}dx$?

Tags: integration, proof-verification, definite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

After I was exploring a kind of integrals, I asked to **Wolfram Alpha** the following code

> $$\int_1^2 \frac{a^{-x}sinh(x)}{e^{2x}-1}dx$$

for its [online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com), to obtain a closed form for $$\int_1^2\frac{a^{-x}\sinh (x)}{e^{2x}-1}dx,$$
where I think that holds for $a\geq 1$. Thus I did the specialization $a=n^{\frac{6}{2}}=n^3$ and after a summation from $$2e^2(\log(a)+1 )\int_1^2\frac{a^{-x}\sinh(x)}{e^{2x}-1}dx=\frac{e}{a}-\frac{1}{a^2},$$
if there are no mistakes, and all my calculations can be justified one gets  $$e\zeta(3)-\zeta(6)=2e^2\int_1^2\frac{(3\zeta'(3x)-\zeta(3x))\sinh (x)}{e^{2x}-1}dx,$$
where $\zeta(s)$ is the **Riemann Zeta function**

> **Question.** **Was right** my identity? **What's about a generalization** for which my identity is a case of your generalization (you can take different specialization or parameters... to write your generalization of my integral)?

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: $\frac{\sinh(x) }{e^{2x}-1}$ ...

Comment: You are w$e$lcom$e$ @user1952009 , thanks

Comment: **All users,** if it is interesting such generalization of related identities perhaps it is possible deduce also identitites using the hyperbolic cosine, since there are relationship with the hyperbolic sine. Perhaps it is possible deduce a formula involving derivatives of high order. I don't know. I understand that the **main Question  was solved by Cantarini.** Thanks for the patience of all users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, essentially you want to know if holds $$2e^{2}\sum_{n\geq1}\left(3\log\left(n\right)+1\right)\int_{1}^{2}\frac{n^{-3x}\sinh\left(x\right)}{e^{2x}-1}dx=2e^{2}\int_{1}^{2}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\left(3\log\left(n\right)+1\right)}{n^{3x}}\frac{\sinh\left(x\right)}{e^{2x}-1}dx.
 $$ Since $1<x<2$ for all $N\in\mathbb{N}
 $ holds $$\sum_{n\leq N}\frac{\left(3\log\left(n\right)+1\right)}{n^{3x}}<\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\left(3\log\left(n\right)+1\right)}{n^{3x}}=-3\zeta'\left(3x\right)+\zeta\left(3x\right)<C
 $$ for some $C>0
 $ and obviously $$\int_{1}^{2}\frac{\sinh\left(x\right)}{e^{2x}-1}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{2}e^{-x}=\frac{e^{-1}-e^{-2}}{2}
 $$ so by the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) we can exchange the series with the integral and so $$\begin{align} 2e^{2}\sum_{n\geq1}\left(3\log\left(n\right)+1\right)\int_{1}^{2}\frac{n^{-3x}\sinh\left(x\right)}{e^{2x}-1}dx=
  & 2e^{2}\int_{1}^{2}\frac{\left(-3\zeta'\left(3x\right)+\zeta\left(3x\right)\right)\sinh\left(x\right)}{e^{2x}-1}dx
  \\ =
 & e\zeta\left(3\right)-\zeta\left(6\right).
 \end{align}$$

For a generalization, We can take every $n^{b},\,b>1$ and with the same calculations we get $$2e^{2}\int_{1}^{2}\frac{\left(-b\zeta'\left(bx\right)+\zeta\left(bx\right)\right)\sinh\left(x\right)}{e^{2x}-1}dx=e\zeta(b)-\zeta(2b).$$ If we take the $p_{n}^{b},\,b>1$ where $p_{n}$ are prime numbers we get $$2e^{2}\int_{1}^{2}\frac{\left(-bP'\left(bx\right)+P\left(bx\right)\right)\sinh\left(x\right)}{e^{2x}-1}dx=eP(b)-P(2b)$$ where $P(s)$ is the [prime zeta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeZetaFunction.html).

Comment: Very thanks much, I wanted known how were justified (specially the swap between the integral  sign and the sum since there were exponentials and signs in the integrand), thus thanks for all your details. I am waiting few days to know more answers and if some provide us a generalization (if such is feasible). Thanks one more time for your nice answer that I am studying.

Comment: @user243301 What do you mean with "generalization"?

Comment: A different contribution to do more interesting my genuine question. Then I understand an identity with parameters such that a specilization of such *generalization* provide us my identity (a right claim) as a particular case. (An additional problem or advantage in this case is that the integral, see the comment of user195209 or mike is obvious, thus one can state also parameters in those functions, if such thing is feasible),

Comment: Also I did the specialization $a=n^{\frac{6}{2}}=n^3$, thus seems possible deduce a more general identity. Very thanks much for your answer and attention. The second question is to do more interesting my contributions in this site.

Comment: Thanks, these details were no obvious, without a full understanding of the right proof, yourself proof.

Comment: @user243301 Try to do my proof with a generic $b>1$, you have to do the same calculations. If there are some problems, tell me and I will add some details.

Comment: I believe that perhaps there are a typo because (if my first claim is rgith) then one has a $b$ in the first identity, I say the factor $$((2e^2b\log n)+1).$$ Very thanks much also for your version for primes!

Comment: @user243301 Yes you are right, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If we return to your original integral, $$ \int_1^2 \frac{a^{-x}sinh(x)}{e^{2x}-1}dx$$ using that $$\frac{sinh(x)}{e^{2x}-1}=\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}$$ we have that your integral is equal to:
$$\frac{1}{2} \int_1^2 a^{-x}e^{-x} dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_1^2 (ea)^{-x} dx.$$  Which has elementary antiderivative, $$\frac{-1}{2} \frac{(ea)^{-x}}{ln(ae)}|_1^2=\frac{-(ea)^{-2}}{2(ln(a)+1)}-\frac{-(ea)^{-1}}{2(ln(a)+1)}.$$  Simplifying a little more gives, $$\frac{-1}{2ea(ln(a)+1)}(\frac{1}{ea}-1).$$ I'm not entirely sure how the Riemann zeta function became involve. I would be very interested to see the details of "if there are no mistakes, and all my calculations can be justified one gets".

Comment: Very thanks much for your contribution and edit of the post. Now you can see Cantarini's answer. My ideas summarized is take $\sum_{n\geq 1}$ on $1/n^{3x}$ (wnenever $x\geq 1$) and get as you know $\zeta(3x)$, or take the sum in $\frac{log(n)}{n^{3x}}$ and one gets the derivative. One  more time see how is justified and the right claim in Cantarini's answer and thanks. Your contribution/answer is valuable since I was wrong, because my integral is more obvious than interesting.

Comment: If you are interested in physics and the Riemann Zeta function, one has the video *La hipótesis de Riemann y la Física*, by **Germán Sierra** available in **YouTube** from the official channel of the **Instituto de Física Teórica** (IFT). The only problem is that is in spanish, but if you have a friend or a colleague that knows spanish this video is incredible. Also seems incredible to me, from same official channel, *Gravedad y Mecánica Cuántica* by **César Gómez**, where is explained what is a constant in physics. Thanks, I hope that you have friends knowing spanish to see the videos

Answer (score 0):

As another people has already pointed out, we have

$$\frac{\sinh(x)}{e^{2x}-1} = \frac{e^{-x}}{2},$$

then, it can be easily seen that your result is the direct application of the [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) method

$$\int_{a}^{b}u\,dv = u v\Big\vert_{a}^{b}- \int_{a}^{b}v\,du $$

applied to the integral

$$\int_{1}^{2}e^{-x}\zeta(s x)dx$$

with

$$u = \zeta(s x) \Rightarrow du = \frac{d \zeta(s x)}{dx}dx = s\zeta'(s x),$$
$$dv = e^{-x}dx \Rightarrow v = \int e^{-x}dx = - e^{-x},$$

therefore, in this particular case,

$$\int_{1}^{2}\zeta(s x)e^{-x}dx = \zeta(s x)\left(- e^{-x}\right)\Big\vert_{1}^{2}- \int_{1}^{2}\left(- e^{-x}\right)\left(s\zeta'(s x)\right),$$

that can be simplified into

$$\int_{1}^{2}\zeta(s x)e^{-x}dx - s\int_{1}^{2}e^{-x}\zeta'(s x) = \frac{\zeta(s)}{e} - \frac{\zeta(2s)}{e^{2}},$$

which is, in essence, the result you have when $s=3$, because $\zeta(s x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{s x}}$, and $\partial_{x}\zeta(s x) = s\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{- \log(n)}{n^{s x}} = s\zeta'(s x)$. In order to generalize this result, just change $\zeta(s x)$ by any other function.